# convert array to new array based on its duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays

I have sample array like below.I want to count each item and store it in different array.

```
one
one
two
two
two
three
random
```

I want the above array to be converted like below or something more easier to get count of items in above array.

```
$arr["one"] = "2";
$arr["two"] = "3";
$arr["three"] = "1";
$arr["random"] = "1";
```

I have an idea like below...Is there any better and easy way to do it ?

```
 foreach($old as $test)
    {

    if (array_key_exists($test, $arr)) {
        $arr[$test] = $arr[$test]+1;
    }
    else
    {
    $arr[$test] = 1;
    }


}
```

Comment: How is it duplicate. ?

Comment: Just use `array_count_values()` and done ?!

Comment: @Rizier123 : that function just count whole array..not particular element.

Comment: Why do you only want to count a particular element? Also you didn't mentioned that in your question, so what do you actually want to do?

Comment: .....I have clearly mentioned how my result should be..I just need to get count of each unique element in first array and store it in another array.

Comment: That is exactly what the dupe shows you..

Comment: @Rizier123 : oops..yea my bad...but how to sort it ascending order?

Comment: Take the function which you need: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: I tried asort($resultarray) but it returns bool(true) ..but var_dump($resultarray) prints all values.

Comment: 1) You took exactly the correct function :) 2) http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php it returns a boolean, since it takes the array by reference. So just call it and your array is sorted, no assignment.

Comment: ok I did , now result of asort is  just printing out values. i.e  counts..

Comment: `foreach($resultarray as $value => $count) echo $value . " => " . $count;`

Comment: thank you ..should I delete question or u will answer ?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844 *Should duplicates be deleted?*